# Dynamically allocated array in a struct unexpectedly modified in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have recently come across the concept of dynamically allocated arrays and in applying it I encountered the following problem.

In a struct I defined some pointers to be allocated later:

```
typedef struct CELL {
 int total;
 int* number;
 char** type;
}CELL;
```

In a function this struct has its memory allocated by malloc(), then the two pointers are allocated an 1D and 2D arrays via following methods:

```
int iallocate1D(int** arr, int m){
 if ( (*arr = malloc(m*sizeof*arr))==NULL ) return 1;
 return 0;
}
```

and

```
int callocate2D(char*** arr, int m, int n){
 int i;
 *arr = malloc(m*sizeof*arr);
 if (*arr==NULL) return 1;
 for(i=0;i<m;i++){
  (*arr)[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(*arr)[i]);
  if ((*arr)[i]==NULL) return 2;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

In the function that takes CELL* as argument, I initialized all arrays:

```
int loadCell(CELL** cell){
 *cell = malloc(sizeof*cell);
 iallocate1D(&(*cell)->number, 2);          // 1D array of length 2
 callocate2D(&(*cell)->type, 2, 3);         // 2D array of size 2*3
}
```

Up to here everything is fine, and I scaned in some values to fill every element of the two arrays. I tested with printf, they seemed ok. And here came the problem, when I modified the value of

```
(*cell)->total = 1;
```

which I thought was not relevant, the 2D char array was also modified. Before this modification char[1][0] == 'L', but after this char[1][0] == '\3'. I printed every element and found that only this element was modified. Weired enough but I could not figure out where it went wrong, as that line was the only thing between the two prints of all array elements. I suspected that my dynamical allocation was wrong, but then I should not have been able to scan some values into the arrays in the first place.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*arr = malloc(m*sizeof*arr)
```

This allocates `m` objects of the size of `*arr`, but you want `**arr`. Some other allocations are similarly missing a level of indirection. They should be:

In `iallocate1D`:

```
*arr = malloc(m * sizeof **arr)
```

In `callocate2D`:

```
*arr = malloc(m * sizeof **arr);

(*arr)[i] = malloc(n * sizeof *(*arr)[i]);
```

In `loadCell`:

```
*cell = malloc(sizeof **cell);
```

Comment: The same problem persists. And I thought (*arr)[i] is already a pointer to char?

Comment: now my code is like       *arr = malloc(m*sizeof(char*)); (*arr)[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(char));      and things remain the old way. I thought if sizeof is followed by a pointer it will return the volume occupied by data pointed by the pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: I will try to come up with a code for testing. The original code was a few thousand lines long. And the problem is you may not reproduce the problem. Without the last line things worked out.

Comment: I think I found out the reason. You are right, sizeof returns the volume of a pointer if it is followed by a pointer. I made the mistake *cell = malloc(sizeof*cell); it should be *cell = malloc(sizeof(CELL)); and correspondingly those arrays. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @robinchm: `*cell = malloc(sizeof **cell)` is preferred to `*cell = malloc(sizeof(CELL))` because the former remains correct if the declaration of `cell` ever changes (e.g., to some new type `CELL2`), whereas the latter requires making an editing in two places (at the declaration and at the `malloc`) and is therefore more error prone.

Comment: Indeed. I am using the format *cell = malloc(sizeof**cell), because I do need to modify the struct CELL often in future coding.